# Excel get values from current and previous rows

Tags: excel-formula, apache-poi, vlookup

I'm trying to get values to dropdownlist from current row and rows above.I used excel's VLOOKUP function.As shown in screenshot given an Account Type(Column A) I want to get it's account name for the current and rows above. 
In order words, when A4 value is ASSET I want to get Account Names(house,furniture,Shop) for dropdown list E4.

```
  CellRangeAddressList parentRange = new  CellRangeAddressList(1, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL97.getLastRowIndex(), PARENT_COL,PARENT_COL);
  DataValidationHelper validationHelper=new HSSFDataValidationHelper((HSSFSheet) chartOfAccountsSheet);
  DataValidationConstraint parentConstraint=validationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint("VLOOKUP($B2,$A$2:$B"+ SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL97.getLastRowIndex()+",2,TRUE)");
 chartOfAccountsSheet.addValidationData(parentValidation);
```

[image]

Comment: This question is only secondary related to `apache poi`. Try at first solving the problem using `Excel`s GUI. Then you will have the formula of the data validation which you then can use in `apache poi` code. Hint: `VLOOKUP` is returning **one** value and not a list of values. But data validation needs a list of values.

Comment: @AxelRichter any appropriate excel function to return a list of values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. 
Create a dynamic named range. 
Go to Formulas --> Name manager --> new and define a range. 
Use this formula for refers to:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B)-1,1)
```

This will create a range from B2 down to the last non empty row. 
 
Then go ahead, highlight the range you want the dropdowns to be. 
 Click data validatio --> list then hit F3 to choose your named range for the list. 
 As you go along your range will expand and the dropdown list will pick the items up. 
Note: It does not take care of duplicates. 
Hope it helps.